# Material UI - DateCalendar defaultValue breaks the application - Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

So i found out about the great functionality from the **Material UI** library and their date pickers and i gave it a try.

So far so good, but i have an issue and i do not know what am i doing wrong.
Here is an example of my code ( normally it is the same as the documentation without the `dayjs` ) :

```
import { DateCalendar } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import moment from 'moment';
...
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null)
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null)
...
const handleDateChange = (newDate: moment.Moment | null) => {
setSelectedDate(newDate)
}
...
return (
...
   <DateCalendar
      disablePast={true}
      defaultValue={currentDate}
      onChange={(newDate: any) =>
      handleDateChange(moment(newDate))}
    />
```

Yeah , i know that i am using `moment` as an defaultValue, but the `TDate` prop that `DateCalendar` expects it wouldn't be a problem.

As an example they are recommending to use `dayjs` as :

```
<DatePicker label="Uncontrolled picker" defaultValue={dayjs('2022-04-17')} />
```

Even though if i pass the dayjs the application still breaks. But if i remove the `defaultValue` from the components it works normal.

I don't think that passing the moment is the problem here.

> Then install the date library of your choice (if not already
> installed). We currently support 4 different date-libraries:
>
> date-fns
> Day.js
> Luxon
> Moment.js

So i wonder what am i doing wrong and what is freezing my application when i try to pass the default date. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from there that i was not passing the right adapter to the provider and that's why the application was crashing.

More about adapters written    [here](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/)

Pass the right adapter on higher level depending on the library that you are using like so :

**DayJS :**

```
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} >
  {children}
</LocalizationProvider>
```

***Luxon :***

```
import { AdapterLuxon } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon';

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon} >
  {children}
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

***Moment :***

```
import { AdapterMoment } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterMoment';

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment} >
  {children}
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

For more information and fixing the Material UI documentation , follow [this](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/8327) link